# How to add multiple authors on IJCAI format

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a paper to [IJCAI conference](http://ijcai-16.org/) (hopefully it will be accepted), and I'm having a bit troubles on inserting a second author.

I know how to do this in general, but I must play by their rule (namely the style file), so unfortunately I have no idea what to do.

The format file can be downloaded from [here](http://ijcai-15.org/downloads/FormattingGuidelinesIJCAI-15.zip).

This is what I thought should work:

```
\typeout{IJCAI-15 Instructions for Authors}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ijcai15}

\usepackage{times}

\title{IJCAI--15 Formatting Instructions\thanks{These match the formatting instructions of IJCAI-07. The support of IJCAI, Inc. is acknowledged.}}
\author{Qiang Yang \\
Hong Kong University of Science and Technology\\
Hong Kong, China \\
pcchair15@ijcai.org
\and
Qiang Yang \\
Hong Kong University of Science and Technology\\
Hong Kong, China \\
pcchair15@ijcai.org}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

But obviously it does not:
[image]

Any ideas? I don't want to mess with their style...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read the comments in the style file carefully (lines 66 ff.): For authors of different institutions, you need to use `\And` instead of `\and`:

```
\typeout{IJCAI-15 Instructions for Authors}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ijcai15}

\usepackage{times}

\title{IJCAI--15 Formatting Instructions\thanks{These match the formatting instructions of IJCAI-07. The support of IJCAI, Inc. is acknowledged.}}
\author{Qiang Yang \\
Hong Kong University of Science and Technology\\
Hong Kong, China \\
pcchair15@ijcai.org
\And
Qiang Yang \\
Hong Kong University of Science and Technology\\
Hong Kong, China \\
pcchair15@ijcai.org}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

(the affiliation might be broken into two lines to avoid the overlap shown in the current state)

Alternatively, if you have multiple authors from the same affiliation, you can do this as follows (note the use of `\and` here instead of `\And`):

```
\typeout{IJCAI-15 Instructions for Authors}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ijcai15}

\usepackage{times}

\title{IJCAI--15 Formatting Instructions\thanks{These match the formatting instructions of IJCAI-07. The support of IJCAI, Inc. is acknowledged.}}
\author{Qiang Yang \and Yang Qiang \\
Hong Kong University of Science and Technology\\
Hong Kong, China \\
pcchair15@ijcai.org
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```